# Overlap on Max/Min dates

Tags: group-by, date, max

I have data in a table that has gotten cut up with multiple start and end dates. This is due to an error that has happened a few times in the last year. Apparently causing the system to not see the record already exists and move on, so the system ends the active record and adds a new one with a new start date.

This should only be happening when there's an actual change on the primary keys (**Account and EffectiveStart**). For now I just need a SQL to get to as few unbroken records as possible and MAX/MIN aren't quite getting me there as it's giving me an overlap between two records. Here is a sample:

#### Sample Data

[image: Sample]

#### My Query

```sql
SELECT Parent,Account,PersonID,TerritoryID, MIN(EffectiveStart), MAX(EffectiveEnd) from testingMaxandMinDates
Group by
Parent,Account,PersonID,TerritoryID
```

#### Bad result set (with overlapping)

[image: Bad Result]

#### Desired result set

The example data at the top shows the following behaviour:

1. There are separate records showing where the account/parent were on one territory/person at first.
2. Then the account/parent/territory moved to a different person.
3. Then the account/parent moved to a different person and different territory.
4. Then the account/parent/territory all moved back to the original person.

So the desired output should display the `MIN(EffectiveStart)` and `MAX(EffectiveEnd)` of each group of records where `Account`, `Parent`, `PersID` and `Territory` where (still) the same.

[image: DesiredResults]

Additional notes in case it's helpful:

- Parent can be the same as Account# but is not always, Parent contains many Accounts including itself.
- A TerritoryID can only have one person on it at a time, but the person can change over time.
- Account can only belong to one Parent and one TerritoryID and one Rep at a time.

Comment: Optimal solution depends on your DBMS and its version. Provide this info. Also add a sample (7-10 rows enough) and desired output for it with detailed explanations according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), pp. 5 and 3.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: Please edit your question following [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)


Check this link out:[How to ask help about a query](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Probably a kind of [gap-and-islands](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem. You basically want the `min(EffectiveStart)` and `max(EffectiveEnd)` of each grouping of `Parent`, `Account`, `PersonID` and `TerritoryID`. Is that correct?  `